# Count key values from a nested object array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
[
   {
        "costs": [{
            "value": "80"
        }],
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Subscription Fee",
        "month": "March"
    },
    [
      {
          "costs": [{
            "value": "200"
          }],
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Tution",
          "month": "March"
      },
      {
          "costs": [{
              "value": "10"
          }],
          "id": 11,
          "name": "DEMO"
      }
   ]
]
```

I need to have sumation of all the values from costs. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
  {"costs":[{"value":"80"}],"id":4,"name":"Subscription Fee","month":"March"},
  [
    {"costs":[{"value":"200"}],"id":2,"name":"Tution","month":"March"},
    {"costs":[{"value":"10"}],"id":11,"name":"DEMO"}
  ]
];

// flatten the arrays to get a list of objects
// iterate over this list
const res = data.flat().reduce((total, { costs = [] }) => {
  // add the values of this item's costs with total
  costs.forEach(({ value = 0 }) => total += +value);
  return total;
}, 0);

console.log(res);
```